# Most used iOS versions

Tags: ios, ios4, deployment-target

I find it hard to locate some kind of information source which will give me a breakdown of the most used iOS versions as of today. I am working on my app and trying to decide on my "Deployment Target". I want to choose iOS 5.0 but not sure how many iOS 4.x users are out there. Does anyone know of a good place to get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look [here](http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/) for iOS usage statistics.

As for me, it's ok just concerning about iOS 5, 6 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about using third party sources for this kind of information.

You only care about marketshare *for your specific app* which will almost always we wildly different to the global average across all apps.

The only real option is to have some kind of tracking in your app, where it sends the OS version to the server once per week for similar for each user.

For a new app, you should support as many version back as you can with a reasonable amount of development effort. Then use actual statistics gathered from your app to decide when to drop old OS versions.

Comment: That's a good point @abhi, will consider that.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to [this](http://modmyi.com/content/12313-apple-s-ios-7-accounts-52-ios-web-share-just-one-week-after-its-launch.html) and [this](http://chitika.com/insights/2013/ios-7-adoption), iOS7 has over 50% usage.